# How can extend the ember-cli build?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to have some custom steps run during them ember cli build, is there a supported way to do that? Specifically, I want to parse comments in css files and build write files to the public directory based on those comments.

Comment: ember-cli is built on [broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli) so you should be able to include any broccoli plugin into your build process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an ember-cli addon to create extra build steps. There is some good documentation around on Google, but [here](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/building-ember-addons) is a blog post I used to create addons. This guide is more tailored toward creating ember components but there are other ember-cli hooks you could use to run code during the build process.

Perhaps you could use the `included` hook to run some code to read your css files and then import your files into the public directory. Other hooks that you could use are documented [here](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/a-compendium-of-hooks-in-embercli#included)

Alternatively, if there is a broccoli plugin that does what you want, you simply need to add it to your package.json and run `npm install`. Now the plugin has been added to the build system.